# System.Threading.Task.WaitAll fails randomly on Windows HPC 2008 without exception

Tags: c#, .net, windows, hpc

I am getting a random crash when trying to execute a small program in a windows HPC 2008 grid when trying to call **System.Threading.Task.WaitAll(tasks)**.

Even though I put the call inside a try/catch, I do not catch any exception. The program exists with a strange exit code **-1073741819**

This is the core code for my thread generator:

```
try 
{   
    var tasks = new List<Task>();   foreach (param in param_list)  {
    tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => MyFunction(param)));   }

    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray()); 
} 
catch(Exception ex) 
{   
  Trace.TraceError("Unexpected error : {0}" , ex.Message); 
}
```

And the threads' code here:

```
static bool MyFunction(int param)
{
  try
  {
    // Do something here
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    Trace.WriteLine("Task for {0} failed: {1} ", param, ex.Message);
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Put your *tasks*' code into try/catch block

Comment: I put my tasks' code into try/catch but no exception is caught.

Comment: Like this? **`Task.Run(() =>{  try {youraction(); }catch (Exception ex) {}});`**

Comment: I updated my question with sample code.

Comment: My problem was due to a 3rd party non-thread safe code called inside my tasks.